# Gradle include all in a flavors libs folder (Compile fileTree whole libs folder)Edit: set sourcedir per flavor for so files

Tags: android, gradle, build-process

So I want to include all files and sub-directories in a flavors file-structure. What I am doing here is including all jar and so files in the libs folder but I also want to include directories.

I tried include `include ['*']` but that didn't work. I also looked around for an answer for a while but came up short. What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

```
dependencies {
    //format for including lib files for all flavors
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //format for including all jars and so's in pdf flavor
    //pdfCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    pdfCompile fileTree(dir: 'src/pdf/libs', include: ['*.jar','*.so'])
}
```

When running app the following exception tells me that not all .so files are included.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.appname-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libPDFNetC-v7a.so"
```

Edit: Below is my file-structure. FYI: src is a child of my module, and is a sibling of libs.
[image]

Comment: What is the solution for it?

Comment: @bhavani I'm not sure if it works anymore or not but 7 years ago my accepted answer did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I could have found a solution by switching up my search criteria, but for those who make the same mistake I will show how I solved this issue.

It seems the real issue was that gradle can only handle jar files in a flavors designated libs folder when using the flavorCompile filetree method.

You can overcome this by designating a `flavor.jniLibs.srcDir` in sourceSets under android. For the file structure below (Which is in a module that I am refusing to show) you can separate a flavors libs files like so.

[image]

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21

        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
        publishNonDefault true
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 21
        }
        //product flavors merge their respective folders in src with main
        productFlavors{
            pdf{}
            nopdf{}
        }
        buildTypes {
            release{
                minifyEnabled false
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                 }
            debug{ minifyEnabled false }
        }
    sourceSets{
        pdf.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/pdf/libs']
    }
    }
    dependencies {
        //format for including lib jar files for all flavors
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //libs jar files for specific flavor
        pdfCompile fileTree(dir: 'src/pdf/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean different **flavours** or different **modules**?

You should have only 1 libs folder per module. Flavours are part of the module and they usually reside in myModule/src/flavourName. As you have 1 build.gradle per module, all flavours share this module's libs dir.

I guess you want to include the libs folders of all modules. Usually that's done by creating a folder on the module directory level, putting all shared libraries in it and then referencing it in each modules' build.gradle file. A bit ugly, but works.

EDIT:  @Theyouthis, can you please add how your directory structure is at the moment. Usually, when it comes to flavours, I've seen structure like this:

```
module1/
      libs/
      src/
         flavour1/
         flavour2/
         flavour3/
      build.gradle
```

So in a structure like this, you'll put all your libraries in libs/ and then they'll be shared for all your flavours.

Comment: I really did mean flavors.

Comment: Edited my answer, please take a look at respond.

Comment: For licencing reasons one flavor must not contain certain files. Updated my question.